# How do I make a POST request from one rails app to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf-protection

I have 2 ruby on rails projects, one that has a form and posts it to the another project. The another project should then convert it to a model, quotation, and save it.

Ive made a quotation resource and a controller with a create method. The form's action is other-project/quotations and method post. From what I understand this should call the create method in the quotation controller.

However I am getting this error:

```
The change you wanted was rejected.
Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.
```

Anyone know what is causing this error? Is it heroku-caused or does it have something to do with my applications? I'm fairly new to rails/heroku so I'm unsure, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit 1**
After some research it seems I need the authenticity tokens to match. However since I have two apps, how is this achieved?

Comment: I don't know if it's the real problem. But each rails app has `secret_token` which can be found in the `initializers/secret_token.rb`. Whenever a form is rendered, an `authenticity_token` is generated for it based on the app's `secret_token`. When the form is posted, the app checks if that `authenticity_token` is valid (again, based on the `secret_token`), if it's not valid the post request is not completed, that might be the reason as you're posting a form of another app!

Comment: are you using a shared db between the 2 apps ?

Comment: No only the 2nd app has the db - @MhdSyrwan, Ok maybe thats the problem then, ill try figure out how I can work the secret tokens -@Tamer Shlash

Comment: What's shown in `heroku logs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after checking heroku logs it does seem to be an issue with CSRF. When I commented out the protect from forgery line in both apps it worked fine and I was able to send data between them.
Will need to some research into whether this is sensible thing to do (guessing not). Thanks for the tips everyone.